# wpf how to clear a region of a DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a DrawingVisual that is partially drawn, and then when I scroll I want to draw the new region and delete the old region from the DrawingVisual. How would I go about cropping out the old region?

Comment: Hmm, can you give us a bit of code here? If you've overridden the render method, I would've expected you'd be starting from a clean slate already - and you shouldn't have to worry about cropping the old parts, only making sure to draw just the new ones.

Comment: I would request that you undelete your recently deleted question about generics. Just because the answer was obvious (no it doesn't work like that), doesn't mean I didn't have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply override your current DrawingContext with empty rectangle - and then draw every new thang as you want, like:

```
var drawingVisual = ...;
var drawingContext = dv.RenderOpen();
var fullRect = new Rect(new Point(160, 100), new Size(320, 80)); //full size rect
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(), new Pen(), fullRect);
//other drawings...
drawingVisual.Close();
```

Comment: This does not work at all. Not to mention that you would be drawing over the first "empty rectangle" by all conseqeutive drawings, but it also just shows up as black regardless. You can't seem to clear the area with a transparent brush, either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question. The drawingvisual's instructions are stored inside it and you can just make a new one, then take the drawingcontext of the new one and draw the old visual while setting a crop region. Haven't tested it yet, but it should work. thanks for the tips everyone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you, but I would start using the clip of any drawing element,
For example, I use this to delete a specific point from the drawing:

```
        Timer DispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += (x, y) =>
        {

            var pos = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            var r = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(Xpos, Ypos, 1, 1)).GetOutlinedPathGeometry();
            var r2 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height)).GetOutlinedPathGeometry();
            i.Clip = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Exclude,r2,r);
        };
        
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(2);
        timer.Start();
```